# web engine - Replace chromium with firefox inside electron app

Tags: firefox, electron, chromium

Is possible to replace chromium with firefox inside an electron app?
I've done some researches and I was not able to found anything that use firefox to run cross platform desktop applications. If this is possible can anyone share the relative information please?

The only project I've found [this old](https://github.com/mozilla/positron) and not mantained from mozilla.

If this is not possible, is there any way to create a custom build of mozilla that integrate node.js? I want to experimet the electron flow that will open a browser window but in a simpler way. I'm reading the mozilla doc, but it's not clear if I can implement external library inside the build and no updated info about custom build creation is found online.

Comment: I doing some research but unfortunately seems that electron is the only stable solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot replace chromium inside Electron because the entirety of how Electron works is using chromium.

As far as if you could do something yourself - I'd say just use Electron. Chromium isn't that bad, although it is resource intensive.

Comment: As you've said chromium is resource intensive and this is bad for desktop applications. I saw some electron alternative projects that will use less resources, I'm thinking on how to build a custom instance of firefox when inside it there is node and a server that will run on opening!

Comment: @newbiedev Then go through Electron's source code

Comment: @Asesh What do you mean?

Comment: Electron's internal are made based and for chromium. Its not like there's node server or something like that, it's just "minified" version of Chromium with extra interface for you to program it.